# Backfill Google Analytics in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking for a workaround on the following issue. Hope someone can help.

- I'm unable to backfill data in the ga_sessions_ table in BigQuery through product linking in GA. e.g.  partition ga_sessions_20180517 is missing
- This specific view has already been linked before. Google documentation says that historical load is only done once per view (hence, the issue) (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en)

Is there any way to work around it?

Kind regards,

Martijn

Comment: Sounds like a query for Google support directly, they should be able to reinstate this missing table for you on an ad-hoc basis.

Comment: I agree with @BenP , this looks like needs support. In this case you'd need to contact [Google Analytics Support](https://support.google.com/360suite/answer/6396567?hl=en&ref_topic=2430414&visit_id=1-636669041230914316-2027972286&rd=2), not Google Cloud Support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Analytics Reporting API to get the data for that view. This method has lot of restrictions like sometimes the data is sampled/only 7 dimensions can be exported in one call, but at least you will be able to fetch your data in a partitioned manner.

Documentation here[Doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a lot of dimensions/metrics in hit level format, [scitylana.com](https://www.scitylana.com) has a service that can provide this data historically.
If you have a clientId set in a custom dimension the data-quality is near perfect. 
It also works without a clientId set.
You can get all history as available through the API.
You can get 100+ dimensions/metrics in one batch into BQ.